# Problem with displaying uploaded images in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

please I have this problem,

I want to upload and display uploaded images in my laravel application.

Here is the code for controller

```
   //testing uploads
    $extension = $request->file('test_img')->extension();
    
    $path = $request->file('test_img')->storeAs(
        'public/id', 'test.'.$extension
    );
```

The image uploads successfully to storage/public/id/test.jpg

Now I have ran the artisan storage command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I want to display this image in my controller like this,

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/id/test.jpg') }}" alt="image">
```

However this does not load the image.

also, after upload if i do a die dump `dd($path);`  it will return  `public/id/test.jpg` but when i visit `https://test-project.local/public/id/test.jpg`  it will return a 404.

I am using laragon for local apache, laravel 9 and php 8

**Modified**

it works now with this. {{ asset(‘storage/id/test.jpg’) }}

Comment: `public` isn't needed as part of the asset path, because `public` is where the root domain will be pointing too.

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('id/test.jpg') }}" alt="image"> also returns 404 too

Comment: Have you checked the file actually exists in the folder?

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes, it exists in storage/app/public/id/test.jpg and as well as public/storage/id/test.jpg

Comment: Weird, route issue perhaps? Doesn't make sense if the file exists, you've done storage link, cleared all the caches possible in the application. If you've done all that and it doesn't show then there's another issue at play

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `public` in your `asset` helper. Just try with:

```php
asset('id/test.jpg');
```

Comment: still return 404,

Comment: Can you see what's going on when you visiting `https://test-project.local/id/test.jpg`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but from console, it’s just logs 404

Comment: I mean can you see image when you provide url from above

Comment: No, I can see any images, just 404 page

Comment: @DingRealT Have you cleared your application's cache etc since you made the storage link?

Comment: @knubbe Yes, I have cleared it severally. But no gain

Comment: @DingRealT Have you check the file actually exists in the folder?

Comment: Yea. It exist in storage/app/public/id/test.jpg as well as public/storage/id/test.jpg

Comment: @AndyHolmes Yea. It exist in storage/app/public/id/test.jpg as well as public/storage/id/test.jpg

Comment: @knubbe it works now with this. {{ asset(‘storage/id/test.jpg’) }}

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with linking storage and public